# Admob Not show in android app

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

I tried many things to do, but nothing helps. My problem is that my admob ad is not displaying and LogCat is writing this:

```
03-23 19:38:36.056: I/Ads(275): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_getSdkConstants();AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":0,"session_id":"13969939755985307547","seq_num":"1","slotname":"a1532f24e29b30a","u_w":320,"msid":"com.app4funmobile.hotsexyasiangirlshd","cap":"m,a","adtest":"on","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1","bas_off":0,"net":"ed","app_name":"1.android.com.app4funmobile.hotsexyasiangirlshd","hl":"en","gnt":3,"carrier":"310260","u_audio":4,"kw":[],"u_sd":1.5,"simulator":1,"ms":"j4bx0mHszPQQ72VXKVPJ1z5L6uL_CLZboEIG6Wy9IJHW_Q-FuhlfkrVApkpMSoBa2tqrFbcCrdnIOQ1Fczm4FAnrDdKFTQIHKCgJnydwSMM0g66VS60_OgW5J_RReilVhfVLHy90AwEh40MVtIcKfYaWGYAnZALEnq5LnGiMumqxMfPuYd1y5VCNQ-_dGRy_2yEhBLzKONNg6NuTvltyR_Gk-5xeJ4TQjQeIOAJGX1Iq4VKEHhN7VS-HgDLmVrEBO6WqXjd2Og-WP0iHfcpzEUu5_enX-8KIdoYPQWqesXkpwJ6aiOGK7hiiOyRjdJXke2oIStrpbtbulNO0sNOE3A","isu":"B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB","format":"320x50_mb","oar":0,"ad_pos":{"height":0,"visible":0,"y":182,"x":0,"width":0},"u_h":533,"pt":1,"bas_on":0,"ptime":0});</script></head><body></body></html>
03-23 19:38:41.266: D/dalvikvm(275): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 3006 objects / 312944 bytes in 215ms
03-23 19:38:41.826: W/webcore(275): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
03-23 19:38:42.216: I/Ads(275): Received ad url: <url: "http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/mads/gma?preqs=0&session_id=13969939755985307547&seq_num=1&u_w=320&msid=com.app4funmobile.hotsexyasiangirlshd&cap=m%2Ca&adtest=on&js=afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1&bas_off=0&net=ed&app_name=1.android.com.app4funmobile.hotsexyasiangirlshd&hl=en&gnt=3&carrier=310260&u_audio=4&kw&u_sd=1.5&ms=j4bx0mHszPQQ72VXKVPJ1z5L6uL_CLZboEIG6Wy9IJHW_Q-FuhlfkrVApkpMSoBa2tqrFbcCrdnIOQ1Fczm4FAnrDdKFTQIHKCgJnydwSMM0g66VS60_OgW5J_RReilVhfVLHy90AwEh40MVtIcKfYaWGYAnZALEnq5LnGiMumqxMfPuYd1y5VCNQ-_dGRy_2yEhBLzKONNg6NuTvltyR_Gk-5xeJ4TQjQeIOAJGX1Iq4VKEHhN7VS-HgDLmVrEBO6WqXjd2Og-WP0iHfcpzEUu5_enX-8KIdoYPQWqesXkpwJ6aiOGK7hiiOyRjdJXke2oIStrpbtbulNO0sNOE3A&format=320x50_mb&oar=0&u_h=533&bas_on=0&ptime=0&imbf=%40installed_markets%40&u_so=p&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=0&client_sdk=1&ex=1&slotname=a1524a20576ec7a&kw_type=broad&gsb=3g&caps=interactiveVideo_th_autoplay_mediation_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di&jsv=79&urll=914" type: "admob" afmaNotifyDt: "null" activationOverlayUrl: "null" useWebViewLoadUrl: "false">
03-23 19:38:42.326: I/Ads(275): Ad url modified to http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/mads/gma?preqs=0&session_id=13969939755985307547&seq_num=1&u_w=320&msid=com.app4funmobile.hotsexyasiangirlshd&cap=m%2Ca&adtest=on&js=afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1&bas_off=0&net=ed&app_name=1.android.com.app4funmobile.hotsexyasiangirlshd&hl=en&gnt=3&carrier=310260&u_audio=4&kw&u_sd=1.5&ms=j4bx0mHszPQQ72VXKVPJ1z5L6uL_CLZboEIG6Wy9IJHW_Q-FuhlfkrVApkpMSoBa2tqrFbcCrdnIOQ1Fczm4FAnrDdKFTQIHKCgJnydwSMM0g66VS60_OgW5J_RReilVhfVLHy90AwEh40MVtIcKfYaWGYAnZALEnq5LnGiMumqxMfPuYd1y5VCNQ-_dGRy_2yEhBLzKONNg6NuTvltyR_Gk-5xeJ4TQjQeIOAJGX1Iq4VKEHhN7VS-HgDLmVrEBO6WqXjd2Og-WP0iHfcpzEUu5_enX-8KIdoYPQWqesXkpwJ6aiOGK7hiiOyRjdJXke2oIStrpbtbulNO0sNOE3A&format=320x50_mb&oar=0&u_h=533&bas_on=0&ptime=0&imbf=8008&u_so=p&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=0&client_sdk=1&ex=1&slotname=a1524a20576ec7a&kw_type=broad&gsb=3g&caps=interactiveVideo_th_autoplay_mediation_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di&jsv=79&urll=914
03-23 19:38:42.336: I/Ads(275): Request scenario: Online server request.
03-23 19:38:43.876: D/dalvikvm(275): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 2628 objects / 436800 bytes in 148ms
03-23 19:38:47.526: W/webcore(275): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
03-23 19:38:48.957: D/webviewglue(275): nativeDestroy view: 0x305f80
03-23 19:38:48.957: I/Ads(275): onReceiveAd()
```

not sure what wrong with code  Will be very greatful for any help My manifest.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.app4funmobile.hotsexyasiangirlshd"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />



<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar"  >
    <activity
        android:name="com.app4funmobile.hotsexyasiangirlshd.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.app4funmobile.hotsexyasiangirlshd.MainActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.app4funmobile.hotsexyasiangirlshd.CategoryItem"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.app4funmobile.hotsexyasiangirlshd.SlideImageActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.app4funmobile.hotsexyasiangirlshd.PinchZoom"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.app4funmobile.hotsexyasiangirlshd.AboutActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

</application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="a1532f24e29b30a"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"
                     ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
                     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>



</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put AdView outside of the ViewPager. ViewPager is made to be populated by an Adapter. You can put your ViewPager and AdView in a RelativeLayout and place 'pager' above 'adView' and 'adview' aligned to parent bottom